# How can I Filter watermark text from XML using XPATH or Apache POI?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, apache-poi

These lines are printing following XML

```
private File file; // path to local docx file
private POITextExtractor textExtractor = ExtractorFactory.createExtractor(file);
XWPFHeader defaultHeader = d.getHeaderFooterPolicy().getDefaultHeader();

String raw_xml = defaultHeader._getHdrFtr().selectPath("*")[0].toString()
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml-fragment xmlns:aink="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/ink" xmlns:am3d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2017/model3d" xmlns:cx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex" xmlns:cx1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/9/8/chartex" xmlns:cx2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/10/21/chartex" xmlns:cx3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/9/chartex" xmlns:cx4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/10/chartex" xmlns:cx5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/11/chartex" xmlns:cx6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/12/chartex" xmlns:cx7="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/13/chartex" xmlns:cx8="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/14/chartex" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:w16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2018/wordml" xmlns:w16cex="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2018/wordml/cex" xmlns:w16cid="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2016/wordml/cid" xmlns:w16sdtdh="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2020/wordml/sdtdatahash" xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape">
   <w:sdtPr>
      <w:id w:val="-1126775779" />
      <w:docPartObj>
         <w:docPartGallery w:val="Watermarks" />
         <w:docPartUnique />
      </w:docPartObj>
   </w:sdtPr>
   <w:sdtContent>
      <w:p w14:paraId="41319DAD" w14:textId="4534348F" w:rsidR="006868D8" w:rsidRDefault="006868D8">
         <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Header" />
         </w:pPr>
         <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
               <w:noProof />
            </w:rPr>
            <w:pict w14:anchorId="63C3AA3C">
               <v:shapetype id="_x0000_t136" coordsize="21600,21600" o:spt="136" adj="10800" path="m@7,l@8,m@5,21600l@6,21600e">
                  <v:formulas>
                     <v:f eqn="sum #0 0 10800" />
                     <v:f eqn="prod #0 2 1" />
                     <v:f eqn="sum 21600 0 @1" />
                     <v:f eqn="sum 0 0 @2" />
                     <v:f eqn="sum 21600 0 @3" />
                     <v:f eqn="if @0 @3 0" />
                     <v:f eqn="if @0 21600 @1" />
                     <v:f eqn="if @0 0 @2" />
                     <v:f eqn="if @0 @4 21600" />
                     <v:f eqn="mid @5 @6" />
                     <v:f eqn="mid @8 @5" />
                     <v:f eqn="mid @7 @8" />
                     <v:f eqn="mid @6 @7" />
                     <v:f eqn="sum @6 0 @5" />
                  </v:formulas>
                  <v:path textpathok="t" o:connecttype="custom" o:connectlocs="@9,0;@10,10800;@11,21600;@12,10800" o:connectangles="270,180,90,0" />
                  <v:textpath on="t" fitshape="t" />
                  <v:handles>
                     <v:h position="#0,bottomRight" xrange="6629,14971" />
                  </v:handles>
                  <o:lock v:ext="edit" text="t" shapetype="t" />
               </v:shapetype>
               <v:shape id="PowerPlusWaterMarkObject357476642" o:spid="_x0000_s1025" type="#_x0000_t136" style="position:absolute;margin-left:0;margin-top:0;width:527.85pt;height:131.95pt;rotation:315;z-index:-251657216;mso-position-horizontal:center;mso-position-horizontal-relative:margin;mso-position-vertical:center;mso-position-vertical-relative:margin" o:allowincell="f" fillcolor="silver" stroked="f">
                  <v:fill opacity=".5" />
                  <v:textpath style="font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;;font-size:1pt" string="CONFIDENTIAL" />
                  <w10:wrap anchorx="margin" anchory="margin" />
               </v:shape>
            </w:pict>
         </w:r>
      </w:p>
   </w:sdtContent>
</xml-fragment>
```

This following XPATH is showing `Confidential`

```
string(//v:shape[contains(@id,'PowerPlusWaterMarkObject')]/v:textpath/@string)
```

How can I use this XPATH to get exact value of Watermark or may be any other way to get watermark in Apache POI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following XPATH solved my problem

```
*//v:shape/v:textpath/@string
```

Answer (score 1):

You had found `org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject.selectPath` already. This allows selecting `XmlObject`s by XPATH. The problem is that the possible complexity of the used XPATH is limited by the kind of XPATH evaluator which can be used by the JRE.

For me (Windows 10, JRE 12.0.2) it needs `Saxon-HE-10.6.jar` to be in class path to enable filtering with predicates. Else the path `$this//v:shape[@id]` results in class not found exception: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.saxon.sxpath.XPathStaticContext`.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFHeader;

import java.util.StringJoiner;

public class ReadWordWatermarkXWPFXPATH {
    
 static String getWatermarkText(XWPFDocument document) {
  StringJoiner stringJoiner = new StringJoiner(" ");
  for (XWPFHeader header : document.getHeaderList()) {
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHdrFtr ctHdrFtr = header._getHdrFtr();
   String declareNameSpaces = "declare namespace v='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml'; ";
   org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject[] selectedObjects = ctHdrFtr.selectPath(
    declareNameSpaces 
    + "$this//v:shape[contains(@id,'PowerPlusWaterMarkObject')]/v:textpath/@string");
   for (org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject object : selectedObjects) {
    if (object instanceof org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlString) {
     org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlString xmlString = (org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlString)object;
     stringJoiner.add(xmlString.getStringValue());
    }   
   }
  }
  return stringJoiner.toString();
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("./WordDocument.docx"));
  String watermarkText = getWatermarkText(document);
  System.out.println(watermarkText);
  
 }
}
```

Simple paths like `$this//v:shape` are possible without having the additional 5 MByte `Saxon-HE-10.6.jar` in class path.

Knowing that, we can do something like this:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFHeader;

import java.util.StringJoiner;

public class ReadWordWatermarkXWPF {
    
 static String getWatermarkText(XWPFDocument document) {
  StringJoiner stringJoiner = new StringJoiner(" ");
  for (XWPFHeader header : document.getHeaderList()) {
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHdrFtr ctHdrFtr = header._getHdrFtr();
   String declareNameSpaces = "declare namespace v='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml'; ";
   org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject[] selectedObjects = ctHdrFtr.selectPath(
    declareNameSpaces 
    + "$this//v:shape");
   for (org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject object : selectedObjects) {
    if (object instanceof com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTShape) {
     com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTShape shape = (com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTShape)object;
     if (shape.getId() != null) {
      String id = shape.getId();
      if (id.contains("PowerPlusWaterMarkObject")) {
       for (com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTTextPath textPath : shape.getTextpathList()) {
        stringJoiner.add(textPath.getString());
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }    
  }
  return stringJoiner.toString();
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("./WordDocument.docx"));
  String watermarkText = getWatermarkText(document);
  System.out.println(watermarkText);
  
 }
}
```